# Access attribute of inherited file

Tags: python, cherrypy, mako

I have the following `base.html` file, which serves as the main skeleton for every other file that inherits it.

```
<%! import cherrypy %>                        
<!DOCTYPE html>                               
<html>                                                                            
  <body>                                           
    <div class="container">
        <% attribute='defaultValue' %>
        ${attribute}   
        <p>                                   
              ${self.body()}                  
        </p>                                  
    </div>                                    
  </body>                                     
</html>
```

Now I have another file that inherits the `base.html`, lets name it `foo.html`:

```
<%inherit file="base.html" />                                                     

Whatever... ${anotherAttribute}
```

The html files will be called in a Python file with `lookup.get_template('foo.html')`.

I can access `anotherAttribute` with `lookup.get_template('foo.html').render(anotherAttribute='bar')`. Now I'm wondering how to access the `attribute` in `base.html`?

Answer (score 0):

you can only share attributes like that via module scope with "attr":

base.html

```
<%!
attribute = 'defaultvalue'
%>
```

foo.html

```
${self.attr.attribute}
```

otherwise base.html would need to pass it directly to foo:

base.html

```
<%
   attribute = 'defaultvalue'
%>

${self.body(attribute=attribute)}
```

foo.html

```
<%page args="attribute"/>

${attribute}
```